# How to insert date picker at product buying page in frontend

Tags: magento2, product

I am developing magento e-commerce site to sell the milk online.

User has to select the date of delivery.How I can ask the user to select the date of delivery at product view page.

Please share your idea and help with me to achieve this use case in magento.

Please share any other alternative ideas to achieve this

Comment: U can find paid plugin online or last u have to create ur shipping method

Comment: By "product buying page", do you mean the checkout page (/checkout/index/index) or the product view page (/catalog/product/view)?

Comment: i have to include date field below the slot attribute at this page.plese see this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qTOxuDCtwnWHR4SlVjV3hVQUE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento provides adding custom option option for product there we can insert whatever kind of input we need.Pleas find the path in admin page

```
product->catalog->edit->customizable option
```